# Algebra structure on Haagerup tensor product of operator spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, tensor-products

> Let $A$ and $B$ be operator spaces. Is there any algebra structure on Haagerup tensor product of operator spaces such that the Haagerup tensor product becomes Banach Algebra?

Any references or ideas?

Comment: If $A$ is arbitrary and $B$ is 1-dimensional, the question amounts to ask whether $A$ can be endowed with a Banach algebra structure? Assuming the Haagerup tensor product to be complete, the question therefore seems to me to be equivalent whether every "operator space" admits a Banach algebra structure. Maybe there are some missing requirements on how the algebra structure should be related to the structure of tensor product?